# Proving vectors of different degrees are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I know that vectors of different degrees are linearly independent? Can you show me an example worked through?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you mean by "vectors of different degrees"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the functions are $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x)=x^3$.  We want to show that if $af(x)+bg(x)=0$ where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, then $a=b=0$.  Let $x=-1$ then $a\cdot 1 + b\cdot -1 = 0$ so we must have $a-b=0$ or $a=b$.  Also, if $x=1$ then $a+b=0$ so $a=-b$. If substitute $a$ for $b$ (because $a=b$) into the second equation you get $a=-a$ and the only solution for this equation is $a=0$.  But then $b=0$ as well. Thus $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are linearly independent.

Comment: That was very helpful. Thanks!